# Assembly successfully added to the cache not found

Tags: c#, .net

When I try to GAC a certain DLL that is in .Net 4.0, it does not show any "Assembly successfully added to the cache" but this DLL is found in the assembly repository "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL". What could be the problem regarding this?

[image: Screenshot when we GAC our DLL]

Comment: @stuartd, using -l or -u does not make any difference, it shows the same output like in the screenshot provided.

Comment: No other error message, it just that we also used gacutil in our codes and one of our condition to check if our gac'ing is successful is if we got the output "Assembly successfully added to the cache"